Asian horror movie about a Demonic book/pages
The Asian Horror flic, I watched had multiple individual short stories, the main story I remember was of these High School kids bullying this guy(resulting in him being dragged from the back of a car) 
The guy ends up returning to the School, holding a demonic book, which causes the person whom sees the given paper/page to be killed by ghosts. The victim begins acting erratic and says he'll get revenge, only to open the book and be killed himself, each of the bullies end up running from the location, only to be haunted by the victim and being killed at a later point.
I recall two major portions from the horror flic, one being that one of the victims decides to go to the media with her being broadcasted on TV only for the lights to black out & her being killed. The other being with the last survivor being placed in protective custody and the ghosts swarming around her & she in turn gauges out her eyes so that she doesn't see the ghost/paper.
I remember another short story which was part of the show, it was surrounding the notion that you shouldn't talk to strangers. Anyway, she's talking to this person online, only for the person she's talking to, to begin saying more stalkerish statements such as, "I know where you are." "I know where you live." The lady ends up closing her laptop, only for her to get a phone call with the same person calling her. In the end she hangs up the phone, only to be texted with the person saying, "I'm coming for you now." "I'm outside your room." "I'm inside your room." And eventually, she tries to leave the room, only for her to be grabbed.
Anyway, If I was to guess, I'd say the show is an Indie production with the show being made in either Thailand, Vietnam, Japan, Singapore, Korea or China, with it being around 7 --> 8 years old.

I think you're after 4bia from 2008; see this answer. One part is about a bullied boy's revenge and the final girl gouges her eyes out, and another is about a girl in her apartment being stalked by text messages.

That's it. :) Thanks for the help. :D
